# Dynamically format output accordingly if its redirected to a file or displayed to console

Tags: java

I want to format the output of my java program so that whenever it’s redirected to a file (xl or csv file) I want the output to be comma separated, but when displayed on console it should not be comma separated. These should be at runtime.

Comment: Could you provide a code sample of what you're currently doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Java 6 onwards we have the Console class. It's instance can be obtained by System.console() method. If no console device is available at runtime then invocation of this method will return null.

```
if(null == System.console()) {
    // write to file
    // code
}
else {
    // write to console
    // code
}
```

Comment: You would then have to add code within these two cases to handle the comma separation or non comma separation as applicable.